# Apex for Admin Trailhead: Code Not Working

Tags: apex, dml

I'm working through the Trailhead and have triple checked my work, watched the video that goes along with the unit, and have researched the problem as much as I know how. The problem is linked here:https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/object-oriented-programming-for-admins/use-sobjects-and-dml?trail_id=build-apex-coding-skills

The following code produces the error:

**Line: 1, Column: 29 Unexpected token '('**.

```
public class AccountHandler {   
   
   public static void insertAccount(Integer newAccounts){
       
       //Creates list to store accounts
       List < Account > addAccounts = new List < Account >();
       
       Integer counter = 1;
       
       while(counter <= newAccounts){
           
           //create new account
           Account a = new Account();
           a.Name = 'Acme Inc ' + counter;
           a.AccountNumber = 'A000' + counter;
           addAccounts.add(a);
           
           //increment counter
           counter++;

       }
       //inserts all items in list
       insert addAccounts;
   }
}
```

Comment: Opened up dev console in a playground, pasted your code into a new class and it saves fine for me.  Are you using Visual Studio Code, and if so have you tried deploying anyway?  Sometimes it takes a bit for VSCode to catch up if it caught an error in an earlier attempt to deploy.  Also of note, it would be helpful to others if you linked the specific Trailhead module you're working on.

Comment: @VictorL. I am using the dev console in a playground as well. It saves fine, but as soon as I use the debugger with this input "AccountHandler.insertAccount(3)" I get the error message.

Good tip about the linked module. I'll edit the post now!

Comment: Did you add a semi-colon to the end of your line `AccountHandler.insertAccount(3)` when you ran it in the developer console?

Comment: What @DavidCheng said - your class is fine, it's the missing semicolon in the Execute Anonymous window (that debugger you're talking about).  I tested it with the semicolon and it'll run.  Remember, statements have to be syntactically correct in the Execute Anonymous window to work.

Comment: Oh man, I feel like such a bozo. Thank you guys.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :^)